# Using VLOOKUP to get info from another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am using the VLOOKUP function for Microsoft Excel.

I am looking at this [tutorial](https://medium.com/import2/join-multiple-data-sheets-in-excel-using-vlookup-function-24e3a27d80cd) here.

I want to join my table with some columns from another worksheet.

I am struggling with the second argument of the function. The id in my first table is in column M.

I moved the ID in the other worksheet to the beginning like the tutorial suggested. The value with which I want to populate the first worksheet is in AA column, how do I insert this in vlookup.

For now:

```
=VLOOKUP(M2,'consent'!)
```

consent is the name of the second worksheet.

Comment: To refer to a range in another worksheet use the following syntax: `'worksheet name'!Range` so for column `A` in sheet `'consent'` use `'consent'!A:A` For column `AA` use `'consent'!AA:AA` (note that the single quotes are optional if the sheet name contains no spaces, but I leave them out of habit)

Comment: When building the formula, just use your mouse to select the ranges. That should work and you don't have to think about how exactly to format the formula.

Comment: To build on what @BruceWayne is saying: In the formula bar, place the cursor where you need a range reference, with the formula bar still active (`Enter` has not been pressed), select the cells on the worksheet the formula should reference (at the formula's cursors location). As needed, select the proper worksheet tab before selecting the range. Then go back to the formula sheet tab and the range will have been populated into the formula with the proper syntax. Highlight the range in the formula bar and press `F4` until the correct relative/absolute address combination is toggled.